# Javaparser method editing

Tags: java, javaparser

Let's say I have a method:

```
void method() {
     int i = 5;
}
```

I want to insert a statement at the very beginning of that method, between { and int i = 5;. How do I do that with javaparser? When visiting methods, ASTHelper.addStmt(..) inserts the statement at the end of the method.

Comment: Take a look on AOP (aspect-oriented programming): https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Try using `ASTRewrite` I can provide you an example as an answer if you haven't tried that before

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. But the thing is I have to use JavaParser. If it's not possible, then I'll gladly accept your example.

Comment: Ok, i give up. Can't do it with javaparser and can't get ASTRewrite to work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the visitor [on the MethodDeclaration](http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/3.0.0-alpha.6/com/github/javaparser/ast/visitor/GenericVisitor.html#visit-com.github.javaparser.ast.body.MethodDeclaration-A-)

Once you have the MethodDeclaration you can get its body ([getBody](http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/3.0.0-alpha.6/com/github/javaparser/ast/body/MethodDeclaration.html#getBody--)) and then access the list of statements composing the body ([getStmts](http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/3.0.0-alpha.6/com/github/javaparser/ast/stmt/BlockStmt.html#getStmts--)). You can your statement in the position you want by calling the add method which accept an index: [add(int, N)](http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/3.0.0-alpha.6/com/github/javaparser/ast/NodeList.html#add-int-N-)

Note: I am referring to the upcoming version of JavaParser, 3.0.0. The API of the current version can be slightly different but you should get the idea

Source: I am a JavaParser contributor